# Android studio mipmap and 9-patch drawables

Tags: android-studio, nine-patch, mipmaps

I am facing strange issue trying to put 9 patch drawables into new android studio mipmap directories. I've put all the images to specified folders, just as I used to do with drawable, but when I try to include it in a project it says

> Cannot resolve symbol @mipmap/myfile

but it definitely "finds" it as you can see at the screenshot.
[image: the actual screenshot]

I think it cannot resolve the symbol because the "real" filename has .9, but dots cannot be used in defining drawable. ( I tried, it didn't work :) )

Is someone esle is facing same problem? Currently, I've added the drawables folders and defined everything eclipse-style and it is working, but It is ugly way to resolve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You must **add all your 9-patch images to drawable** folder and use it by referencing **@drawable/your_image_name**.

For more information refer [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

Comment: that's what I've did as for now

Answer (score 1):

Compilation and IDE resolution are 2 different things. Android studio can find your mipmap image but the android sdk does not support naming convention with 2 dots when you try to compile. Just rename your image to `greenbuttonbg.png`.

Comment: but if I rename it, would it behave as a 9-patch drawable? Or it will become static ?